# How to get an item by itemId in Circuit JS SDK?

Tags: circuit-sdk

I handle a formSubmission event on Circuit using Circuit JS SDK. Then I update an item that contains this form by using method **updateTextItem**. I want to save previous value of **item.content**. But received event contains only **itemId**. Is it possible to get item by itemId to get content?

```
client.updateTextItem({
      itemId: event.itemId,
      form: {
          id: event.form.id,
          // content: ???,
          controls: [{
                type: 'LABEL',
                text: submittedValue
          }]
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use API `getItemById` or `getItemByIds`.
https://circuitsandbox.net/sdk/classes/Client.html#method_getItemById